# How to start selenium standalone server ith IE11 webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I'm trying this command in order to start selenium standalone server with internet explorer 11:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.ie="C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe"
```

where MyUser is my current username.
But I'm getting exception.

Using selenium standalone server version 2.53.1 works fine with the same arguments but it's recommanded to use the same version for IE webdriver and selenium.

Here's the exception I have:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Was passed main parameter '-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\Xavier\Downloads\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\IEDriverServer.exe' but no main parameter was defined in your arg class  
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.initMainParameterValue(JCommander.java:936)  
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:752)
[...]
```

Does anyone know how to run it ?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by moving -jar .... at the end of the command:

```
java -Dwebdriver.ie.driver=C:\Users\MyUser\Downloads\IEDriverServer_x64_3.14.0\IEDriverServer.exe -Dwebdriver.ie="C:\Program Files\internet explorer\iexplore.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar
```